# Sub setting a block of elements inside a vector

Tags: r

Say I have a vector. I need to select every two elements. I need to do this in a loop and pass it on to different vector

for eg
A<-c(1:10)
i want to select  elements like
(1,2) (3,4),(5,6) and so on and pass the sum of these two elements into another vector.
required output is (3,7,11,15)

Comment: I added more relevant links, see if they are helpful.

Comment: The example in your edit seems completely different from what you first described. Search back through previous SO posts, but if you can't find something that helps, maybe you should post a different question with a [clear example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you need to do